# Can I deploy two ASP.NET (MVC and WebApi) applications side-by-side?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-web-api2

I am working on an ASP.NET project. We have two main projects, and MVC website, and a WebApi2 application that it uses to interface with the datebase.  All of the routes of the WebApi2 application are something like "/api/Entity"  I would like it so that our main MVC site that users are actually hitting will be hosted in the domain root (ie. www.example.com), while being able to access the api at "www.example.com/api/Entity".  Is there a way to do that without doing a bunch of IIS configuration, or changing my routes?

Comment: why dont you have them in the same web project?

Comment: Because they are separate applications.  I don't want them to be intertwined like that.  Separation of concerns.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can place them in the same project.
2. You can create an application within IIS called api and change the route definition in the api project to remove the `/api/`. Doesn't seem like a bunch of configuration/changing routes.

Comment: I want to avoid doing #1 if I can.  I have considered doing #2, but that would require me to change all my routes, though, most are done via "RoutePrefix" so it wouldn't be too bad.  There are things in my API that refer to their relative urls though (using HAL+JSON), so the API itself does know that it is hosted at /api, so I'm not super keen on putting that in the hands of IIS.  I don't think there is another way though.